# How to replace values of an isolated scope when uses the "@" for text attributes on Angular 1.4 directive? (works in Angular 1.3)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to use attribute as strings in my html. So I don't need to use any more scope variables.
My issue is actually defining some default values. But I realized, that when I use '@' in Angular, I'm not able to change this value in Angular 1.4, I was able to do using 1.3.

Is there a way to define default values on Angular 1.4 directives when using text attributes (@)?

I've tried replace my values on compile, compile Pre and Pos, link and controller and it's not replacing.

I could use '=' instead and define my attributes as string, but that's actually "Uggly":

Eq. `<ribbon title="'my title as string, but forces the single quote use'">`

Link for Plunker with Angular 1.3.1 working: http://plnkr.co/edit/onThA71Q5SE5scU7xOez

The snippet is using Angular 1.4

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', [])

        .directive('ribbon', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    title: '@',
                    subtitle: '@'
                },
                template: '<span class="ribbon"><strong>{{title}}</strong> <i>{{subtitle}}</i></span>',
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.title = $scope.title || 'Ribbon';
                    $scope.subtitle = $scope.subtitle || 'Default';
                }
            };
        });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
        <li>I have a
            <ribbon></ribbon>
        </li>
        <li>I have a
            <ribbon subtitle="customized"></ribbon>
        </li>
        <li>I have a
            <ribbon title="Custom ribbon" subtitle="customized"></ribbon>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like there is a problem, do not know if it is a breaking change or not. it looks fine if you assign it asynchronously, with `scope.$evalAsync`. http://plnkr.co/edit/UB0uqVssFZhu6oC14HrA?p=preview More like the value gets overwritten when the directive renders and after the postLink phase.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PSL. That was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about the existence of scope.$evalAsync. I'll study about it. Worked like a charm.

Comment: yw. By the way you could do this way as well. http://plnkr.co/edit/CHy0FeocEw1L1udEzmxb?p=preview

Comment: Awesome. I've tried using the attrs way before, but I didn't create an empty scope, so didn't work. Need to study more about it. Thanks again!

Comment: Really nice @PSL! Write as an answer for both of your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a breaking change or a bug with 1.4, version of angular. However you could use slightly different ways to tackle this problem.

1) Deferring the default assignment. Since it looks like even if you set the value on the scope, (controller instantiation happens first) somewhere on the postLink phase it gets overwritten by the value (no value here so undefined) bound. You could use **[`$scope.$evalAsync`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync)**

```
  $scope.$evalAsync(function(){
       $scope.title = $scope.title || 'Ribbon';
       $scope.subtitle = $scope.subtitle || 'Default';
  });
```

2) Use isolated scope with no bindings (`scope:{}`) (just so you don't pollute its parent scope by adding properties), or child scope `scope:true` and read the values from the attributes as you are binding them statically anyways.

```
  $scope.title = attr.title || 'Ribbon';
  $scope.subtitle = attr.subtitle || 'Default';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug that was fixed in Angular 1.4.4.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[Fork of the plunker; changed angular version to 1.4.4](http://plnkr.co/edit/rUMKuXgHGlp0qdOT0sHY?p=preview)